# Error:(5, 9) Error: Element type "style" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: android

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="android:style/Theme"
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#e90707</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Unable to execute !also the in themes.xml is showing red item name?

here is manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Its unfortunately stopped working!

Comment: Please learn to read your error messages. What wasn't clear in `Element type “style” must be followed by either attribute specifications, “>” or “/>”`?! It explicitly tells you what to do to fix your typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the material concept of android:

Add in styles.xml

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Add in colors.xml

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
```

I hope this will help you.....

Answer (score 2):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>

   <style name="MyCustomTheme" 
 parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#2268ff</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>




   </style>

 </resources>
```

yes Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#e90707</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

It is Markup language.

Comment: It is against site policy to debug for someone. But my answer is tested and right.

Comment: Learn "xml". it is a "mark up language". these are necessary for android development.